# Laravel - Composer Autoload Error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have created a file in `App\Helpers\Common.php`. Inside this file I have defined some constants. In local it works great but when I uploaded it in a shared host, it returns an error saying:

```
[04-Dec-2017 03:39:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/bibbibco/public_html/main/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bibbibco/public_html/main/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
[04-Dec-2017 03:39:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/bibbibco/public_html/main/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/common.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in /home/bibbibco/public_html/main/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

I have added in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
"files": [
    "App/Helpers/Common.php"
]
}
```

to load the files, but it returns the error mentioned above.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try adding a starting `/` in the file path?

Comment: It doesn't care. I have deleted it completely to see what happens but nothing :( because I think it has cached it and I don't have SSH access to `composer update` it.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the application directory in Laravel is `app` not `App`.

If you're using Windows either `App/Helpers/Common.php` or `app/Helpers/Common.php` will work because paths are not case-sensitive. Using Linux, `app` and `App` are distinct so only `app/Helpers/Common.php` will work.

Comment: Yeah! Damn to Windows|Linux Separation!